# TFS New Build and Build Process Template (XAML): How to pass/get unique build request ID

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am calling a console application from within a TFS build process template (copied of DefaultTemplate.xaml).  I would like to pass a the unique "Request ID" to the app.  I cannot find an argument or parameter in the XAML with this value.  Nor can I find much documentation on the "Request ID", however I know one must exist based on the Build history.  The build history "View Summary" tab shows a request ID (ex: "Request 12345").

[image: Request 23322, requested by ---- 4 days ago]

How can I get this value within the template (xaml)

Edit: In the TFS Database (tfs_defaultcollection), I believe this is tbl_Build.BuildID

Comment: I was able to get the TFS Request ID through a collection on the BuildDetail object:
"BuildDetail.RequestIds.Item(0)"
I have to verify the value has a value though.  This seems a little convoluted.  Why are there multiple Request IDs associated with a build?  Nevertheless it appears to work.

Answer (score 1):

Its a string but it looks like `BuildNumberFormat` is available via the build process.  I also see `BuildDetail.BuildNumber`.

Comment: That is not what I am looking for, the BuildNumber looks like: My_TFSBuildName_20160216.1".  This is a unique name, but I am looking for an integer ID. In the TFS DB, I think this is tbl_Build.BuildID (integer)

Comment: I don't see build id but the Build Number looks like the next best thing.  For example "buildNumber":"20151026.1".

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the TFS Request ID through a collection on the BuildDetail object: `BuildDetail.RequestIds.Item(0)`.  This is a collection so I need to verify it has values and that Item(0) is not null.

I am not certain why RequestIds is a collection?  I assume theoretically you can have more requests associated with a build?  Not necessarily clear, but certainly consistent with the TFS build process.